# Limit MPI to run on single GPU even if we have single Node multi GPU setup

Tags: mpi, distributed-computing, gpgpu, hpc, amd-rocm

I am new to distributed computing and I am trying to run a program which uses MPI and ROCm(AMD framework to run on GPU).

The command I am using to run the program is 
`mpirun -np 4 ./a.out`

But it is defaultly running on the available 2 GPUs in my machine.
Is there a way to make it run only on single GPU and if yes how?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Have you tried any of these ideas and envvar : https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/issues/841 ? For instance ROCR_VISIBLE_DEVICES

Comment: Thanks @Demi-Lune, HIP_VISIBLE_DEVICES worked for me. But, can MPI has control on which GPUs to use?

Comment: You may pass env vars to mpirun with `-x` : `mpirun -np 2 -x HIP_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1,2 ./a.out`

Comment: But maybe you're looking for a way to set GPU#0 for some process ranks #1 to other ranks? You could try to `setenv("HIP_VISIBLE_DEVICES", rank%2);` in you mpi program, right after the mpi_init?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may control the active GPU(s) by setting some environment variables
(e.g. `GPU_DEVICE_ORDINAL`, `ROCR_VISIBLE_DEVICES` or `HIP_VISIBLE_DEVICES`, see [this](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/issues/711) or [this](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/issues/841) for more details).

For instance:

```
export HIP_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
mpirun -np 4 ./a.out
# or 
HIP_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 mpirun -np 4 ./a.out
```

Be careful that some MPI implementations do not export all environement variables, or may reload your bashrc or cshrc. So using your MPI's syntax to set envvars is safer:

```
# with openmpi 
mpirun -x HIP_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 -np 4 ./a.out

# or with mpich
mpiexec -env HIP_VISIBLE_DEVICES 0 -n 4 ./a.out
```

To be on the safe side, it's probably a good idea to add this to your C++ code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
// ...
char* hip_visible_devices = getenv("HIP_VISIBLE_DEVICES");
if (hip_visible_devices) std::cout << "Running on GPUs: " << hip_visible_devices << std::endl;
else std::cout << "Running on all GPUs! " << std::endl;
```

(note that cuda has both an envvar and a C-function CudaSetDevice(id), I'm wondering if there's an equivalent for AMD or openCL).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @Demi-Lune

Comment: For AMD, there is an equivalent for CudaSetDevice() which is [hipSetDevice()](https://rocm-developer-tools.github.io/HIP/group__Device.html#ga43c1e7f15925eeb762195ccb5e063eae), but I am not sure regarding OpenCL.